# What does it mean zend_extensions_psa in phpinfo?

Tags: php

I need to install some PHP extension and a the extension is zend_extensions_psa.

I'm on ubuntu 10.04 and PHP is 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSA typically refers to [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/), a server management console used to allow clients to manage their own websites on your server. This extension seems to be part of that

http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-260762.html

> Found a file called zend_extensions_psa.ini on /etc/php5/conf.d with
>   this content:
>
> ; Following directives were moved from php.ini files by Plesk to avoid
>   load order errors
>   ; Please do not add any zend_extension* or extension
>   directives directly into php.ini

It sounds deprecated from that information. Check to see if you have a `zend_extensions_psa.ini`